# mvn clean compile Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in:

Tags: java, maven

my path

```
C:\Users\Administrator\mvnDemo>echo "%path%"  
"C:\Program Files\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program
Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin;D:\folder\setup\Sp
ringSetup\apache-maven-2.2.1\bin;"
```

my home path

```
C:\Users\Administrator\mvnDemo>echo "%java_home%"
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20"
```

when I run mvn clean compile on windows 7 command prompt I get errors

```
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------- [ERROR]
BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
---------------------------------------------------- 
[INFO] Compilation failure Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in:  
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\..\lib\tools.jar Please ensure you
are using JDK 1.4 or above and not a JRE (the
com.sun.tools.javac.Main class is required). In most cases you can
change the location of your Java installation by setting the
JAVA_HOME environment variable.
```

I have tried for other  reference but didn't get proper solution
Thanks in advance

Comment: Set your classpath for JAVA,Like when we compile java program from Command prompt,since MAVEN is a java program it require jdk.thats why its throwing error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple. You are using a JRE (Java Runtime Environment), but you need a JDK (Java Development Kit). Go, download a JDK, adjust your PATH and JAVA_HOME env variables accordingly, and try again.

Re-looking at your question. The environment variable is JAVA_HOME, not java_home

Comment: Thanks it Worked.  I downloaded JDK and set path accordingly .

Comment: How do you know OP used JRE instead of JDK?

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov because the error message literally said so :-)